# Sqlite through C not returning results where plain sqlite is

Tags: c, sqlite

Writing a program to retrieve data from an sqlite database keeps returning no results despite the exact same query in the sqlite cli returning the expected results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

sqlite3 * db;
sqlite3_stmt * locationgetint;

int locationInt(char * string){
    sqlite3_bind_text(locationgetint,1,string,-1,SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_step(locationgetint);
    int output = sqlite3_column_int(locationgetint,0);
    sqlite3_clear_bindings(locationgetint);
    sqlite3_reset(locationgetint);
    return output;
}

int main(){
    sqlite3_open("db.sqlite3",&db);
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,"SELECT id FROM pfs WHERE name='?';",-1,&locationgetint,0);
    printf("%d\n",locationInt("Milky Way")); // Prints 0
    return 0;
}
```

But the Sqlite CLI version:

```
sqlite> SELECT id FROM pfs WHERE name='Milky Way';
625
sqlite>
```

Comment: I think you do not need the quotes in the SQL statement, i.e. `WHERE name=?`.

Comment: Well last time I removed them I broke something so I decided to leave them in

Comment: Wow, he was right... Which is strange cause last time I removed those quotes I broke something. Add a question and I'll check it off thanks sjoerd :)

Comment: `WHERE name='?'` does exactly what it would in the command-line. Looks for line with value `?`.

Comment: Except it doesn't work here... Removing the quotes fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sjoerd said, removing the quotes worked.